# Solution Check for Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[image: Q1]

Solution is 4.

Original matrix is simply [v1;v2;v3;v4]. It forms an identity matrix. Hence the only alteration of the determinant comes from row 1 operation where v1 is multiplied by 2. Then the determinant will also be multiplied by two so 2*2 =4.

We ignore the rest of row operations since they have no effect on the determinant.

Is this line of reasoning correct?

Comment: No. 2on row is multiplied by 4 and 4th row is multiplied by 2.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802752/row-replacement-operation-not-changing-the-determinant/1802789

From other sources, it appears that it does not have effect on determinant. Only row 1 has an effective change on the initial determinant A = 2

Comment: Adding a multiple of a row to another row does not affect the determinant. But you are adding a multiple of a row to a MULTIPLE of another row, so the determinant gets affected.

Comment: I understand now. So in this case, we have three effects on the determinant.
1) first row is multiplied by 2. 
2) Second row is multiplied by 4.
3) fourth row is multiplied by 2. 

Then in effect, our determinant is now 2*4*2*2? So 64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that:
$$\begin{align}|A|=\begin{vmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{vmatrix}&=2 \Rightarrow \\ 
\begin{vmatrix}2v_1\\4v_2\\v_3\\2v_4\end{vmatrix}&=32 \ \ \ \ \ \stackrel{\frac32R_1+R_2\to R_2\\ \frac14R_2+R_3\to R_3\\ \frac12R_1+R_4\to R_4}{\Rightarrow} \\
\begin{vmatrix}2v_1\\3v_1+4v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_1+2v_4\end{vmatrix}&=32.\end{align}$$

Comment: This was very concise. Thank you!

Can you answer this question as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871861/the-matrix-denotation-clarification-on-shear

Comment: My pleasure, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\begin{vmatrix}2v_1\\3v_1+4v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_1+2v_4\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}v_1\\3v_1+4v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_1+2v_4\end{vmatrix}=2\begin{vmatrix}v_1\\4v_2\\v_2+v_3\\2v_4\end{vmatrix}=16\begin{vmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_2+v_3\\v_4\end{vmatrix}=16\begin{vmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{vmatrix}=32$$

To check we can try with

$$\begin{vmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{vmatrix}=2$$

and

$$\begin{vmatrix}2&0&0&0\\3&4&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&0&0&2\end{vmatrix}=32$$