# Prove that the determinant of the following $n\times n$ symmetric matrix that consists can be found by the following formula

Tags: linear-algebra

A is an $n\times n$ symmetrical matrix that has a diagonal of zeros, first row and column are ones with the rest of the entries equal to a real number d

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&.&.&.&1\\1&0&d&.&.&.&d\\1&d&0&\
.&.&.&d\\.&.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.&.\\.&.&.&.&.&.\\1&d&d&.&.&.&0\end{bmatrix}

prove that $$|A|= ((-1)^{(n-1)}\cdot(d^{(n-2)})\cdot(n-1)$$

I have tried finding the determinant the usual way but that turned out to be so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

replacing one column at a time of the matrix with a combination (to be specific, a linear combination where any coefficients are either $1$ or $0$ ) of the other columns e.g. for the 2nd column of $\mathbf{A}$ denoted as $\mathbf{A}^2$, we could replace it thusly $$\mathbf{A}^2 \to \mathbf{A}^1 + \mathbf{A}^2 + \mathbf{A}^3 ...$$
And the determinant will not change (see [Row replacement operation not changing the determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802752/row-replacement-operation-not-changing-the-determinant) - this works with row as well as column replacements). See you if you can use this fact to simplify the matrix.